# Set & Get methods - Java

Tags: java, methods, get, set, tostring

I am new to Java and have been set some tasks to complete, so far I have completed the first section shown below:

"1. Design a class Manual with the following properties:

serial number - string, - default:??????

title - string, - default: Untitled

author - string, - default: Unknown

Write a constructor and a method to print details of a Manual on the console. "

Code:

```
public class Manual {

    String serialNumber, title, author;

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Manual man= new Manual();
        man.printDetails();
    }

    public Manual(){
        serialNumber = "??????";
        title = "Untitled";
        author = "Unknown";
    }

    public void printDetails(){
        System.out.println("Serial Number = " +serialNumber+" Title = "+ title+" Author = "+author);}



}
```

For the next section I have been required to:

"2. Amend your Manual class by writing the following additional methods: methods to set and get the properties of a Manual

a method to ask the user for details of a Manual

a toString() method. "

So far I have attempted the set & get method part of the section and my code is as follows:

```
public class Manual {

    String serialNumber, title, author;

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Manual man= new Manual();
        man.printDetails();
    }

    public Manual(){
        serialNumber = "??????";
        title = "Untitled";
        author = "Unknown";
    }

    public String getserialNumber(){
        return serialNumber;
    }

    public String gettitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public String getauthor(){
        return author;
    }

    public void setserialNumber(String serialNumber){
        serialNumber = ??????;
    }

    public void settitle(String title){
        title = Untitled;
    }

    public void author(String author){
        author = Unknown;
    }

    public void printDetails(){
        System.out.println("Serial Number = " +serialNumber+" Title = "+ title+" Author = "+author);}



}
```

Would anyone be able to tell me wether the code I have thus far is correct & if any changes need to be made. Also, any help assisting on the next tasks will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You can ask for a specific problem in your coding, not in general. You can't expect the guys at stackoverflow to write the complete code for your assignment. If you are stuck at a bug in your code, and can't find or unable to find a solution online, you will surely receive help.

Comment: So what's the .. problem? Besides the fact it won't even compile. Hint: `author = Unknown` in the author "setter" should be `this.author = author`. For starters, `Unknown` is an unknown identifier.. secondly the parameter variable shadows the instance member variable, which is why the `this.` is important. The same changes apply to the other "setters". Finally, there is a conflict with the member variable `author` and the method `author`.

Comment: @ArslanAli Im not expecting anyone to do the work for me. Im simply ensuring that my workings are all clearly shown to avoid confusion, I only asked for help on the next tasks as an invitation for advice, not answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. I can see you're confused about your setters. Title, Author, and Serial Number are variables accessible to the whole class, so in your setters you can directly place values inside of them. In the parameter of your setters, you should have a different name than the names of these variables. For example:

```
public void setTitle(String t)
{
    title = t;
}
```

the function will have a string passed through its parameters (String t) and that value is placed inside title. Right now, you're placing the default values into the variable setters, and that is incorrect. The default values are for the default constructor, which you did correctly. To help you understand a little more, I'll give you an example of what your test classes might look like:

```
Manual myManual = new Manual(); //now that the Manual Object has been instantiated, 
                                //the variables contain the default values from your 
                                //default constructor.

myManual.setTitle("Some Title"); //"Some Title" was passed through the parameters of the 
                                 //setTitle method, and the title variable in Manual is equal
                                 //that value
```

On a side note, you could always capitalize the beginning of a word following the first word in titles of methods, variables, etc. setTitle, getAuthor, etc

---

EDIT:

The first snippet of code is how your setters should look in the Manual class. You should change all your setters to look similar in format. The second few lines with all the comments would be in the main method.

Also, I looked at your pastebin code and you still are setting the variables in your setters to the default values. That is not correct. You should be setting your variable to whatever was passed through the parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried to make the suggested changes and here is my updated code: http://pastebin.com/FC2hg4H7 - Sorry if there are still mistakes, Im not sure if what I have done is correct :(

Comment: Also, where would I implement your code snippet examples? Within the Manual class?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think your code compiles!?
The purpose of getters/setters is, to change(set) or GET an object.
Your setter should look either like this:

```
public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
}
```

or this:

```
public void setTitle(String anotherVariableName){
        title = anotherVariableName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have made the suggested changes to the set methods. When I run the code this is printed to the console: "Serial Number = ?????? Title = Untitled Author = Unknown
" is this printing because of the fact that I have set "Author = unknown" or is it from above in the code where I defined the variables and added a print method?

Comment: You didn't define any variables. Do you understand what a setter is supposed to do? It assigns the parameter to the class variable. What is author = unknown supposed to do?? Edit all your setters as I suggested above.

Comment: weren't the variables set at the top of what I posted? the author = unknown is the default value for author until a new author is entered by the user (next stage) I have updated my setters as above and here is what my code looks like now: http://pastebin.com/FC2hg4H7

Comment: Yes, they were. But as you wrote these are **default** values. If you want to change them later, you use setters.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct:

1. Your method names do not follow method naming rules as they are not camelCase.
2. There is a method 'author' that sets an author. It should be: 'setAuthor'.
3. What are the 'Unknown' things in 'settitle' and 'author' methods?

Have you even tried to compile it ?!